# Nested folders in Static Resources

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources

I have a set of components that have image references to static resources in LWC. I want to upload the static resource with a nested folder structure for thumbnails etc:

So the images.zip file would look like:

```
resource.zip
 -images
  --thumbs80
  --thumbs200
  --thumbs600
 -file.png
 -file2.png
```

The components would then reference the {resource}\images\thumbs80\thumb80.png for example. When I upload this folder from VSCode it creates the resource.zip with only the file1 and file2 include, not the nested folders of images.

Is this a new limitation as this is an old code base that used to work like this?